# Error while Running iOS simulator from Xcode on Mac

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am unable to open my iOS Simulator. Whenever I run my iOS App on Xcode it displays the following error:-

```
failed to start launched sim could not bind to session launched_sim may have
```

Could anyone please let me know how could I resolve this issue? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @zeytin yes, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to Xcode preferences and from tab "Locations", directly open "Derived Data" directory and delete it

or

- Go to here and make `Device -> Erase All Content and Settings`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 edited my answer this approach will be more easy